# bootsnap/setup load error on all rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

No matter which rails app I try to run `rails s` on, I get this error below. This error started occurring after following this tutorial:

https://hackernoon.com/make-a-slideshow-using-ruby-on-rails-in-50-lines-of-code-and-no-javascript-9fdf0a88ec9d

and after I installed the gem fie.

I was finally able to get `rails s` to work by commenting out require bootsnap in the config/boot.rb file. That was after a lot of cleanup and resetting spring. I've Googled this every way and can't find an answer. I removed my tmp folder and all kinds of other tactics to no avail. Please help me, I want to know how I messed up my gems and why it is not working! Thank you!

````
    15: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    14: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    13: from /Users/flatironschool/Playful/fun_with_rails_through_students_and_schools/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
     8: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     6: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     5: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
     4: from /Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
     3: from /Users/flatironschool/Playful/fun_with_rails_through_students_and_schools/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/flatironschool/Playful/fun_with_rails_through_students_and_schools/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
     1: from /Users/flatironschool/Playful/fun_with_rails_through_students_and_schools/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/Playful/fun_with_rails_through_students_and_schools/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)```
````

Comment: I think I saw this error before, and it might be in assets/javascript/application.js could you comment out bootsnap there if it exists?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately this happens for every rails app I create. Even when I use ```--api``` and there is no javascript folder in assets.

Comment: Hi I also get the same error on my macbook, have you solve this problem? thanks